# Long John and the Persian poet

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Blast forty-second drink, about half pint (3,5,4)
>   8. Kind of fabric of which a suit is cut (3)
>   9. Fast and furious drama with vacuous action (7)
>   10. Part of keyboard amplifier containing moisture (4)
>   11. Winter activity for king in South India (3)
>   12. Foreign capital smuggled to Slovakia (4)
>   15. Fictional forest creatures sent around (4)
>   17. Soft cat sound over Lima repeated (6)
>   21. Perfectly pass a college's entrance exam's first part (3)
>   22. No horse's cry heard (3)
>   23. Hydrogen in the periodic table... 1st, true? (6)
>   25. Man forgetting large lottery (4)
>   26. Arms twisted, which is comfortable (4)
>   27. A Greek island is built around love (3)
>   30. Great Britain, for example, is large – #1 in Europe (4)
>   32. The part in common to cover laptop attributes (7)
>   34. Deadlock struck as Stack Exchange is an evil entity (3)
>   35. Perhaps a true Bosnian is an Englishperson from the south? (13)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Leave lake in Ireland following endless anger (8)
>   2. Missing Iran's capital, Persian poet getting something to drink with Long John (3)
>   3. In short, a race of 500 miles in 500 years (4)
>   4. Happily ensure keeping change in Japan (4)
>   5. Grounds for having small amount of money sent (8)
>   6. Type of milk shunned by South Korean leader (3)
>   7. City on the border of Eastern Alps shaken by volcano, ultimately (2,4)
>   13. Depend on being thin (4)
>   14. Previously 100-in-1 (4)
>   16. Examination about links to the most irritable (8)
>   18. Perhaps last predecessor of the euro (4)
>   19. Only one protecting French city (4)
>   20. Secretly drawing Spanish aircraft's measurement (8)
>   24. Appearing in London Times according to schedule (2,4)
>   28. Having change of heart, go away to New York neighbourhood (4)
>   29. Fare badly, getting the heebie-jeebies (4)
>   31. Type of resort missing in most of Iberia (3)
>   33. For the audience, put down a flowery ornament (3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations (using the usual notation: `*` for anagram, `_..._` for hidden word, `..._` for first letter extraction; the rest should be fairly self-explanatory):

> [image]

Some comments on the puzzle:

> The grid has several instances of two unchecked cells in a row -- this is conventionally not done for cryptics. It's not a huge deal because those entries are generally relatively well-checked, but I can see it being a potential problem for FURLOUGH and WINGSPAN. Generally, blocked cryptic grids have a "lattice" pattern with blocks two apart, and then more blocks are added to rows and columns to split them. (This prevents the need for a lot of three-letter words, too.)
>
>  Some of the definitions don't quite work. 9A is defined as "fast", but Ramadan is a month, not the fasting that happens during that month. 11A is defined as "winter activity", but that would be SKIING, not SKI. And in 4D, the plural of YEN-the-currency is still YEN; YENS is only the plural of YEN in the sense of "desire".
>
>  A few clues have the grammar 'backwards': in 12A, 25A, 5D, and 31D, the indicators don't grammatically apply to the words they're supposed to cryptically modify. (For example, in 12-A, "X smuggled Y" is interpreted as "the string Y hides X", but it *should* be "the string X hides Y".)
>
>  There also appear to be a few extra words: 6D's "by", 13D's "on", and 21A's "exam" don't seem to make sense in the clues. (In addition, that last one should have "first parts", because you're taking multiple "first parts", not just one.)
>
>  Oh, and I *loved* 8-across -- a very nice surface, with "kind of fabric" looking very much like a definition. The "... of which ... is cut" construction was great too. It took me a while to spot - I haven't seen it before, but it works very well, and the reinterpretation required to solve the clue is very clever. 28A is also a nice clue, with the "change of heart" wordplay being a nice departure from the usual "replace the middle letter with an annoyingly unspecified one".

Comment: Hmm yeah, I seem to have gotten into the habit of putting "X doing Y" as "doing Y X", which might work with a comma between Y and X but not really without it... I'll look into using the lattice pattern as a starting point. That could also help get rid of words with no unchecked letters, resulting in clues that aren't needed at all for the completion of the grid. (It'll be a while before I get to post those, though, since I have the next several grids already laid in advance.) Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I interpreted 21A as: "a + entrance to college + first part of exam" which makes the clue fit.

Answer (score 6):

Since English is not my native language, but I love Dutch cryptic crosswords, I'll try to solve a few ones:

10 across:

> damp (found in 'keyboarD AMPlifier')

12 across:

> oslo (capital of Norway, found in 'tO SLOvakia')

13 down:

> lean (to lean on is to depend on)

14 down:

> once (C = 100 in 'one' = 1)

15 across:

> ents (treefolk from Tolkien, obtained from putting the s in 'sent' at the end)

21 across:

> ace (first letters of A College's Entrance)

23 across:

> honest (Hydrogen = H + '1st' = onest)

24 down:

> ontime (found in 'londON TIMEs')

31 down:

> spa (Iberia = Spain, subtract the 'missing' 'in')